# How to communicate DataGridView Row Index to Presenter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mvp, bindinglist

I have a `DataGridView` on the form and I've bound a `BindingList` to the `Grid` in my `Presenter`.

```
public AttendancePresenter( IAttendance model, IAttendanceView view, IDataService dataService, IMessageService messageService ) : base(messageService)
{
    _BindingAttendanceList = new BindingList<IAttendance>();
    _View.AttendanceGrid = _BindingAttendanceList;
}
```

Now I want to delete the selected row from the grid when I press Delete button (and this change should be updated back on the database). My question is how should I inform the `Presenter` that I want to delete this particular row / item in the grid? If presenter knows that it can find the deleted item from the `BindingList` and delete the same record from the database too. (ID field `AttendanceID` field could be used in this regard)

**NOTE:** My `View` doesn't know about the `Presenter`. `View` just fires event upon user actions.

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnDeleteAttendance(sender, e);
}
```

**EDIT:** My grid has several columns like `AttendanceID`, `EmployeeID`, `Name`, `InDateTime`, `OutDateTime` etc. and I'm using a public property in the View to set Grid from Presenter

```
public BindingList<IAttendance> AttendanceGrid
{
    Set { dgvAttendance.DataSource = Value; };
}
```

Comment: Please share your Grid markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are essentially asking is how to pass the `ID` of the item you want to delete from the **View** to the **Presenter**.

There are 2 typical ways you can do that:

1. Create a property in the **View** interface that is used to get the `ID` of the item you want to delete.

   ```
   public int IdToDelete
   {
       get
       {
           // logic to get the id of the item you want to delete
       }
   }
   ```

   This way in your Presenter you get access to the ID of the item you want to delete.
2. The other way would be to extend the `EventArgs` class and add another property for storing the ID of the item but I think that would be an overkill for passing a single value.